# Android Fragment: How understand that DB table was changed?

Tags: android

android, **API 15**

DB: **OrmLiteSqlite**

`Fragment#1` show data in db `tables#1.`

`Fragment#2` show data in db `tables#2.`

Also have `toolbar` with a button.
When click on this button, in the db `table#1` and `table#2` change some data.
How `Fragment#1` and `Fragment#2` can understand that db tables was changed?

Comment: as usual ...  `((INotifier)getActivity()).notifyAllFragmentsThatDataHadChanged(this)` ... of course parent activity should implement `INotifier` ... and implementation will iterate all fragments which implements `IMyDataObserver` and call `dataChange` method

Comment: ... or you can implement `ContentProvider` and use Loaders API ... and you will get it automagically (well if your implement it properly)